# Search a URL list, return JSON values into a dynamically generated table

Tags: theming, forms, search

I am looking for a Drupal Service or a Module (or a link to a working example) of this arrangement:

There's a Search form. Placing and submitting the search will make a REST call for certain values to a URL which is a JSON list, generated by an API, then - return those JSON values and display them in a generated table.

I hope that I have explained this well enough. So, which Drupal Service/Module can do the job described above? I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you for looking at this Post and I appreciate your help in pointing me in the right direction!